# A Message for the Solver!

Tags: rhyme, steganography

Stealth mode is     always turned on
The place    where I come from
Everything    looks genuine in here
Great things   are being taken care
Another message    waits for you my friend
Nice little gaps have a compliment  to send
Only the things you    see are irrelevant, I say so
Giving up is not  an option though
Rare codes preserves   a message for you to solve
And   this one will definitely help you evolve
Please come back when you    need me
Here I    am waiting with the key
Yes, the key is right here. Wait until you see -= .=

**Hey, I just left you a nice message. Can you find it?**

<sub><sup>(Note-It's not too obvious !)</sup></sub>

Comment: It reads much nicer backwards than forwards :P

Comment: @n_palum Oh yes, it does :)

Comment: Oh, man, key makes me think vigenere. (*Runs to hide under bed*)

Comment: @Sid You may wait until you see it :)

Comment: I feel like this might be related to steganography.

Comment: I'd suggest adding the [tag:steganography] tag, now that the puzzle is solved.

Comment: This made me feel pretty smart :D

Comment: Anyone else see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I66ta.png)?

Comment: @2012rcampion I saw that once I posted it :p Fortunately, no one caught it ;) I thought, I had an older browser or something like that which doesn't handle unicode.

Comment: @2012rcampion yeah, close to it. I'm using the SE app (on Android FWIW) and just see ` ` (a square with an X through it pretty much) edit:hm, copy pasting it doesn't work. Anyways it's a tall rectangle with an X through it)

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k573g.png) is how it looks to me. Extreme steganography. Loved the puzzle and the little note.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The secret message is:

> YOU ARE GENIUS

Taking the first letters of each paragraph you find the hint:

> STEGANOGRAPHY

Looking for something *between the lines*...

> Copying and pasting the message into a text editor like notepad++ you can see some special characters (line separators or paragraph separators) for each line in the text.  Interpreting them line separators as dashes and paragraph separators as dots and dashes you obtain the following code:  -.-- --- ..- / .- .-. . / --. . -. .. ..- ... which translated using Morse Code gives the intended (at least I hope so!) solution!

**OP Edit**

> The riddle talks about Steganography and rare codes(Unique codes - UNICODE) inside the gaps(spaces) Using a simple [Unicode decoder](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) we get -
>
>
>  Stealth mode isU+2028 U+2029 U+2028 U+2028 always turned on
>  The placeU+2028 U+2028 U+2028 where I come from
>  EverythingU+2029 U+2029 U+2028 looks genuine in here
>  Great things U+2029 U+2028are being taken care
>  Another message U+2029 U+2028 U+2029waits for you my friend
>  Nice little gaps have a complimentU+2029 to send
>  Only the things youU+2028 U+2028 U+2029 see are irrelevant, I say so
>  Giving up is notU+2029 an option though
>  Rare codes preservesU+2028 U+2029 a message for you to solve
>  AndU+2029 U+2029 this one will definitely help you evolve
>  Please come back when youU+2029 U+2029 U+2028 need me
>  Here I U+2029 U+2029 U+2029am waiting with the key
>  Yes, the key is right here. Wait until you see -=U+2028.=U+2029
>
>  The riddle says, the things you see is not relevant also the last line says the key is *-=U+2028 and .=U+2029*
>
>  Hence, we get the message above :-)

Comment: Nicely and quickly done! Here's a green tick!